# SonarQube Plugin Development in Issue View

Tags: sonarqube

Dear SonarQube Community,

I have a general question regarding is it possible to write a plugin that will extend the Issue View? See screenshot and its red marks. 
I looked at the API for Plugin Development and didn´t find a part where I can do that.

[image]

I want to develop for SonarQube 6.x

Thank you!
Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ability to extend this part of the UI.